# Store Image Using Rest Request using AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

how to store image in MySql using Angular as data is passed in json as Rest request to java backend server which i have used spring MVC.

Comment: loak at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21015891/spring-mvc-angularjs-file-upload-org-apache-commons-fileupload-fileuploade

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you should give a try first and then come here to post questions, but here it is how you can get started:

1) [Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21015891/spring-mvc-angularjs-file-upload-org-apache-commons-fileupload-fileuploade) from your browser to the Web Server

2) [Persist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26154091/correct-way-to-upload-binary-file-to-mysql-through-spring-mvc) your image (binary file) into MySql

Try to integrate from these examples and come back if something fails.