# Initialize database with binary data in web servlet app

Tags: java, spring, database, h2, spring-framework-beans

I have next working code with ddl and dml. Its initialize embedded H2 database.

```
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(@Value("${jdbc.driver}") String driver,
                             @Value("${jdbc.url}") String url,
                             @Value("${jdbc.user}") String user,
                             @Value("${jdbc.password}") String password) {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(driver);
    dataSource.setUrl(url);
    dataSource.setUsername(user);
    dataSource.setPassword(password);

    Resource initSchema = new ClassPathResource("schema.sql");
    Resource initData = new ClassPathResource("data.sql");
    DatabasePopulator databasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator(initSchema, initData);
    DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(databasePopulator, dataSource);

    return dataSource;
}
    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    jpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
    jpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory =
            new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
    entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan("org.doit.model");
    entityManagerFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
    return entityManagerFactory.getObject();
}

@Bean
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
    return transactionManager;
}
```

Pls give me advise, how to insert in database the binary data, like a zip file that is located in the resource folder.
I know that in unit test we can use annotation @Before which give us opportunity to do what you want. But how do it when you start your app with java config.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same issue.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26195062/17238919) answer worked for me. You can try it, I think this will work for you.

Comment: Very strange sql script will be)
If file will be more than 100 bytes its unreal to write scripts)))